# vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT vs vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT

Tags: vulkan

As a Vulkan noob, I see vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT used in tutorials,which looks similar to OpenGL [Debug Output extension](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output). Both also share same enumerators. 
Please explain the difference and use case.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the question title (which desires a comparison between two functions in the same API) and the question text (which desires a comparison between two *different APIs*). So what comparison do you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are/were two extensions in Vulkan that involve handling this kind of debug report callback stuff: `VK_EXT_debug_report` and `VK_EXT_debug_utils`. Debug report was the first one and has essentially been abandoned in favor of the second. Debug report was *solely* devoted to providing a callback interface, while debug utils provides APIs for naming things and various other debugging systems.

Debug report is [officially a deprecated extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/chap44.html#VK_EXT_debug_report), so going forward, you should [use debug utils](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/chap44.html#VK_EXT_debug_utils).